# rpm version number without installing it

Tags: rpm

I need to get the version number of an rpm file like "`foo-[RELEASE].rpm`"

I tried these commands

```
rpm -q --queryformat '%{VERSION}' foo-[RELEASE].rpm 
package foo-[RELEASE].rpm is not installed

rpm -qp --queryformat "[%{VERSION}\n]" foo-[RELEASE].rpm
```

I need to replace the **[RELEASE]** placeholder with the version number.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Taking an example of `sbt.rpm`, here is how you may want to extract the information. Note that the package filename itself doesn't show the version and release information.

Get full package name:

```
$ rpm -qp sbt.rpm
sbt-0.12.2-1.noarch
```

Get NAME, VERSION, RELEASE and ARCHITECTURE separately:

```
$ rpm -qp --queryformat '%{NAME}' sbt.rpm
sbt

$ rpm -qp --queryformat '%{VERSION}' sbt.rpm
0.12.2

$ rpm -qp --queryformat '%{RELEASE}' sbt.rpm
1

$ rpm -qp --queryformat '%{ARCH}' sbt.rpm
noarch
```

Get NAME, VERSION, RELEASE and ARCHITECTURE combined:

```
$ rpm -qp --queryformat '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}-%{ARCH}' sbt.rpm
sbt-0.12.2-1-noarch
```

Get only NAME, VERSION:

```
$ rpm -qp --queryformat '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}' sbt.rpm
sbt-0.12.2
```

Comment: Thanks for responding tuxdna, but it didn't work. Not getting any output

Comment: I am using `RPM version 4.11.1` on `Fedora release 20`. Perhaps that might make a difference. Also, can you update in question what commands you tried this time?

Comment: I tried all the commands suggested by you and not getting any output. I'm using RPM version 4.8.0 and centOS 6.4

Comment: Thanks tuxdna, the problem is not with the commands but its with the rpm file. I tried with a different rpm file and the commands are working.

Answer (score 3):

```
 rpm -qip foo.rpm
```

shows version number :

```
Version     : 1.3.4
```