# RegEx for parsing package name, package version (including release) for Fedora / Red Hat packages

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

My goal is to parse correctly package names and package versions (including release number) for Fedora or Red Hat packages like this:

```
python39-3.9.16-1.module+el8.8.0+18968+3d7b19f0.1.x86_64
python3.11-3.11.2-2.el9_2.2.aarch64
glibc-2.34-60.el9.aarch64
glib2-2.68.4-6.el9.aarch64
langpacks-core-font-en-3.0-16.el9.noarch
p11-kit-trust-0.24.1-2.el9.aarch64
tzdata-2023c-1.el9.noarch
```

Expected result:

```
pkg: python39   version: 3.9.16-1
pkg: python3.11 version: 3.11.2-2
pkg: glibc  version: 2.34-60
pkg: glib2  version: 2.68.4-6
pkg: langpacks-core-font-en version: 3.0-16
pkg: p11-kit-trust: version: 0.24.1-2
pkg: tzdata version: 2023c-1
```

Here is my attempt:

```
echo -e "python39-3.9.16-1.module+el8.8.0+18968+3d7b19f0.1.x86_64\npython3.11-3.11.2-2.el9_2.2.aarch64\nglibc-2.34-60.el9.aarch64\nglib2-2.68.4-6.el9.aarch64\nlangpacks-core-font-en-3.0-16.el9.noarch\np11-kit-trust-0.24.1-2.el9.aarch64\ntzdata-2023c-1.el9.noarch" > pkgs.txt
cat pkgs.txt | sed -E 's/([^-]*)-([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*(-[0-9]+)?)([^0-9].*)?/pkg: \1\tversion: \2/'
```

and i'm getting:

```
pkg: python39   version: 3.9.16-1
pkg: python3.11 version: 3.11.2-2
pkg: glibc  version: 2.34-60
pkg: glib2  version: 2.68.4-6
langpacks-core-font-pkg: en version: 3.0-16
p11-kit-pkg: trust  version: 0.24.1-2
pkg: tzdata version: 2023
```

Please help me to fix/improve a regular expression to parse correctly package names and package versions

**UPDATE**
I'm going to execute this command in a container with minimum installed OS packages (similar to `ubi-minimal`). So I won't have `perl` and `python` installed, just a minimum set of commands like: `cat`, `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, etc.

Comment: It is probably a better option to get the version from the Fedora or RedHat built-in package manager tool `rpm`, rather than attempt at parsing unreliable names formats like `rpm -qp --queryformat '%{VERSION}' package.rpm`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21496161/7939871

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495717/rpm-version-number-without-installing-it/21496161#21496161

Comment: @LéaGris, thank you for your answer! It's partially answers my question - it solves an issue if I'm parsing packages installed locally. But I'd still want to be able to parse them even if i'm getting a list of packages installed on another machine.

Comment: Running `rpm` on the remote machine is possibly an option like `ssh remote-host rpm ...`

Comment: It looks like `2023c-1` is the only "wrong" result? Your pattern is only allowing for digits after the dash: `(-[0-9]+)` - You could make it less restrictive e.g. `s/([^-]*)-([0-9][^-]*-[0-9]*).*/` - but it's unclear if all possible package names follow that exact format, hence the suggestions of querying the package manager.

Comment: Thank you @jqurious, with the updated RegEx it does parse `tzdata-2023c-1.el9.noarch` correctly, but it doesn't parse `langpacks-core-font-3.0-16` and `p11-kit-trust-0.24.1-2.el9.aarch64`

Comment: Did you notice that Philippe's answer already provides a `sed` solution? Does that not work for you?

Comment: @tripleee, nope, i've missed that. Thank you for the heads up! :)

Comment: Ah right. Yeah, it's probably not possible with a single pattern in sed due to a lack of non-greedy support. Just to correct myself: `sed -E 's/\.[^0-9].*//; s/-([0-9].*)/ version: \1/; s/^/pkg: /'` - which is essentially equivalent to the answer below.

Comment: See [Parse an RPM name into its components](https://serverfault.com/q/557350).

Comment: @pjh, beautiful answer, thank you) It's a pity I can only accept one answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use perl :

```
perl -pe 's/(.*?)-([0-9].*?)\.[^0-9].*/pkg: $1\tversion: $2/' << EOF
python39-3.9.16-1.module+el8.8.0+18968+3d7b19f0.1.x86_64
python3.11-3.11.2-2.el9_2.2.aarch64
glibc-2.34-60.el9.aarch64
glib2-2.68.4-6.el9.aarch64
langpacks-core-font-en-3.0-16.el9.noarch
p11-kit-trust-0.24.1-2.el9.aarch64
tzdata-2023c-1.el9.noarch
EOF
```

`sed` version, assuming there is no @ in package name :

```
sed -E 's/\.[^0-9].*$// # Remove everything after version
        s/(-[0-9].*)/@\1/ # Insert @ before version
        s/([^@]+)@-(.*)/pkg: \1\tversion: \2/' << EOF
python39-3.9.16-1.module+el8.8.0+18968+3d7b19f0.1.x86_64
python3.11-3.11.2-2.el9_2.2.aarch64
glibc-2.34-60.el9.aarch64
glib2-2.68.4-6.el9.aarch64
langpacks-core-font-en-3.0-16.el9.noarch
p11-kit-trust-0.24.1-2.el9.aarch64
tzdata-2023c-1.el9.noarch
EOF
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I'd like to avoid using perl, because this command is going to be executed in the container based on ubi-minimal Red Hat image with the minimal number of installed OS packages. If I would need to install `perl` additionally - that would require to install a LOT of new OS packages.

Comment: Neither of the solutions works in general.  Try with the (real) Fedora package `java-17-openjdk-17.0.6.0.10-1.fc38.x86_64`.  The package name is `java-17-openjdk`, the version is `17.0.6.0.10`, the release is `1.fc38`, and the architecture is `x86_64`.  (Java packages have the major version embedded in the name to allow multiple versions to be installed at the same time.)  The required output for this package is `pkg: java-17-openjdk version: 17.0.6.0.10-1`.  Both of the suggested solutions produce `pkg: java version: 17-openjdk-17.0.6.0.10-1`.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following Perl one-line solution. Using regex `^(.*?)-([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*(?:\.[0-9]+)*(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)` here which creates 2 capturing groups which we are using to print values while performing substitution here as per required output.

```
perl -pe 's/^(.*?)-([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*(?:\.[0-9]+)*(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)/pkg: $1\tversion: $2/'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I won't have perl available in a container where I will have to run this command. I've updated my question correspondingly.

Comment: @MaxU-standwithUkraine, sure not an issue, I have added another answer below this thread(https://stackoverflow.com/a/77256052/5866580) with `awk` if that helps you, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

If your container has the `rpm` command then it provides the safest way to do what you want (as described in at least one other answer).

If you don't have the `rpm` command then you can do what you want fairly easily and safely by depending on the RPM package naming standard as documented in [Format of the RPM File](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-file-format.html).  The format is `name-version-release.architecture` (NVRA).  Since internal hyphens (dashes, `-` characters) can only occur in the `name`, and the `architecture` never contains a dot, it is straightforward to parse the package name into its parts.

A portable (no `-E`) `sed` solution is:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)-\(.*-[^.]*\).*/pkg: \1 version: \2/' pkgs.txt
```

It can also be done with standard shell string manipulation.  I (lightly) tested this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code with `bash` and `dash`:

```
#! /bin/sh -

while read -r nvra || [ -n "$nvra" ]; do
    nv=${nvra%-*}
    ra=${nvra##*-}
    n=${nv%-*}
    v=${nv##*-}
    printf 'pkg: %s version: %s-%s\n' "$n" "$v" "${ra%%.*}"
done <pkgs.txt
```

The pure shell code would be noticeably slow if the `pkgs.txt` file is large (I'd guess over 1000 lines) though.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an `awk` answer here, since OP said `perl` may not be there in their container. Used GNU `awk` here.

- Making field separator as `(\\+|\\.)el[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]*)*` as per shown samples.
- Then using `match` function to match regex `-([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*)([^-]+)(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?` to get versions values here.
- Then again using `match` function to get values before version, would have done it more easily if `awk` would have support lazy match :)

```
awk -F'(\\+|\\.)el[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]*)*' '
match($1,/-([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*)([^-]+)(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/,arr){
   val=arr[1] arr[2] arr[3]
}
match($1,val){
   print "pkg: " substr($1,1,RSTART-2) "\tversion: " val
}
'  Input_file
```

***OR*** use `column` command after `awk` one to get output in Good looking format.

```
awk -F'(\\+|\\.)el[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]*)*' '
match($1,/-([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*)([^-]+)(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/,arr){
  val=arr[1] arr[2] arr[3]
}
match($1,val){
  print "pkg: " substr($1,1,RSTART-2) "\tversion: " val
}
' Input_file | column -t
```

Answer (score 2):

Using RedHat or Fedora provided `rpm` package manager to return the name and version is undoubtedly more reliable than using a Regex to parse package names.

Example:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
for pkg in
  python39-3.9.16-1.module+el8.8.0+18968+3d7b19f0.1.x86_64 \
  python3.11-3.11.2-2.el9_2.2.aarch64 \
  glibc-2.34-60.el9.aarch64 \
  glib2-2.68.4-6.el9.aarch64 \
  langpacks-core-font-en-3.0-16.el9.noarch \
  p11-kit-trust-0.24.1-2.el9.aarch64 \
  tzdata-2023c-1.el9.noarch
do
  rpm -qp --queryformat 'pkg: %{NAME} version: %{VERSION}' "$pkg.rpm"
done
```

Or if having all `.rpm` file names, a loop is not even required:

```bash
rpm -qp --queryformat 'pkg: %{NAME} version: %{VERSION}' \
  python39-3.9.16-1.module+el8.8.0+18968+3d7b19f0.1.x86_64.rpm \
  python3.11-3.11.2-2.el9_2.2.aarch64.rpm \
  glibc-2.34-60.el9.aarch64.rpm \
  glib2-2.68.4-6.el9.aarch64.rpm \
  langpacks-core-font-en-3.0-16.el9.noarch.rpm \
  p11-kit-trust-0.24.1-2.el9.aarch64.rpm \
  tzdata-2023c-1.el9.noarch.rpm
```